# Best way to render variables inside html you get from an API in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So Using VueJS I'm getting some html content from my api, I wanna render it somewhere in my view and then change whats inside double curly braces e.g `{{title}}`, I know that `v-html` does only render the html not any variable or so, I tried replacing it with js (replace, match and stuff) since I know my regex and it worked fine but the thing is... I want it to be editable by user in my web app, like when user inputs some value inside certain fields, its changes corresponding value in html that Im rendering which originally came from api, and finally send them back so I have them in db (I'm currently putting value and replace it with some default string just to be able to show something sane using `v-html` directive), Im asikng for best practices and your ideas here ppl, thanks in advance...

*I need to get the number of valuables in {{mustaches}} and be able to edit only those not entire html

Comment: v-html cant interpolate `{{ title }}` etc, your want to use something like [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template) package

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the value in a data property. And then change it however you like, with an input, method, etc:

Demo: https://codepen.io/aQW5z9fe/pen/vYLyYXo?editors=1011

### Code

```html
<textarea
  @input="inputEventHandler"
  v-model="htmlData"
  placeholder="HTML data"
></textarea>

<div v-html="htmlData"></div>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    htmlData: ''
  }
},
mounted () {
  // Get data from API
  this.htmlData = this.getData()
},
methods: {
  getData () {
    return 'Data from API'
  },
  inputEventHandler (event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually want only certain parts of html to be editable (every double curly braces needs a field and needs to be editable) not entire html. thank you for your answer